# Spring expression 'literal' in XML config file

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a simple class something like:

```
public class ValueProvider {
     public void setExpression(String expression) {
         this.expression = expression;
     }


     public String getValue() {
         Expression exp = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(this.expression);
         return exp.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(new Foo()), String.class);
     }
     private String expression;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to register the provider it tries to evaluate the provided expression:

```
<bean class="com.ValueProvider">
    <property name="expression" value="#{bar}" />
</bean>
```

Any ideas for how to get Spring to treat the value attribute as a string/expression literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the state of [SPR-704](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7041) this is not possible.

Comment: Although not possible, there was a link from that bug report: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82798-Simple-question-of-SPeL-in-xml-files&p=291683#post291683 that does have a workaround, using value="#{'bar'}" to surround the expression *inside* the #{} with single quotes. Thanks for the help!